# SQL Server 2008 another way to do this

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

![enter image description here][1]

Brings the correct results of one row freespace,avg and days left. Would have to do another query to get the latest freespace. can use row_number rank but that would bring back 700. Any way to do this better rgs

```
declare @top  int=3
declare @dept varchar(20)='dept_a'

select * from dept

select top(@top) * 
from dept
where usage<0
order by datestamp desc


select  
    freespace ,
    avgDay,
    (freespace/avgDay) as daysLeft 
from 
    (select top(1) freespace 
     from dept 
     where deptname = @dept 
     order by datestamp desc ) as freespace,
    (select avg(usage) AvgDAy 
     from
          (select top(@top) * 
           from dept
           where usage < 0 
             and DeptName = @dept
           order by datestamp desc) as AvgSel
    ) as AvgDay
```

**Data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/210dd/1**

**Results for Dept A -** 
920 freespace 
133 avg day 
6 days left
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/210dd/2

**Results for Dept B -** 
400 freespace 
66 avg day 
6 days left
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/210dd/4

Comment: Do *what specifically* better? You have dumped SQL and results and very little description of what the data means and what the result means. Can you explain what you're actually trying to get here? Also, please post the SQL as text in future posts, makes it easier for people to fire up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to try out varies solutions.

Comment: Thanks i have updated with the sqlfiddle link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically your query, if I understand correctly:

```
select  freespace ,avgDay,(freespace/avgDay) as daysLeft
from (select top(1) freespace
      from dept
      where deptname = @dept
      order by datestamp desc
     ) as freespace cross join
     (select avg(usage) as AvgDAy
      from (select top(@top) *
            from dept
            where usage < 0 and DeptName = @dept
            order by datestamp desc
           ) as AvgSel
     ) as AvgDay
```

A more efficient form would be:

```
select max(case when seqnum_1 = 1 then freespace end) as freespace,
       avg(case when seqnum_2 <= 3 and usage < 0 then usage end) as dailyusage,
       (max(case when seqnum_1 = 1 then freespace end) /
        avg(case when seqnum_2 <= 3 and usage < 0 then usage end)
       ) as days_left
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (order by datestamp desc) as seqnum_1,
             row_number() over (partition by (case when usage < 0 then 1 else 0 end)
                                order by datestamp desc) as seqnum_2
      from dept
      where dept = @dept
     ) d
where seqnum_1 = 1 or (seqnum_2 <= 3 and usage < 0);
```

In general, window functions are going to be faster than `order by`.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/210dd/10) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: thanks right direction but getting wrong figures http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/210dd/8  Results for Dept A sould be - 920 freespace 133 avg day 6 days left

Comment: @winchmore . . . The SQL Fiddle really helps.